# Using the Perl index function to find each instance of a sequence and then replace it with a different character

Tags: perl, loops, indexing

I want to replace each nucleotide in a DNA sequence with a - unless it matches a certain sequence. The location where the sequence is found should print a |. I want to do this using the index function. I am trying to get it to print dashes until it reaches the location in the index, in which case it would print a | and then continue through the rest of the sequence finding each instance.  Basically, if the sequence is found at locations 2, 6, and 9, I would want the output to print (starting at 0) --|---|--| in a different txt file. I'm having trouble trying to get my code to work. Could someone explain why it is not working? I should probably also mention that I am pretty new to Perl and programming in general, so my logic might be off.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open INPUT ; # input and output are txt files
open OUTPUT ;

undef $/;
my $sequence = do { local $/; <INPUT> };

while (<>) {
    my $EcoRI = "GAATTC";
    my $off = 0;
    my $count = 0;

    my $totalnt = 4970982;  
    my $line = "|";
    my $dash = "-";

    while ( my $index = index($sequence, $EcoRI, $off) ) {
        $off = $index + 1;
        $count++;

        if ($count ne $index ) {
            print OUTPUT $dash ;
} 
        elsif ($count eq $index) {
            print OUTPUT $line ;
}
        last if ($count eq $totalnt) ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons your program does not work as expected.

- `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` are both blank file handles. If used this way, it will attempt to open a file name contained in `$INPUT` and `$OUTPUT` respectively. And it will give an error when used if those variables are empty. This is an arcane quirk of the very versatile `open` command.
- You are undefining `$/` twice, both when slurping your input, and then outside that block as well, which affects the `while(<>)` loop afterwards. There really is no need to do this, unless you have more than one line in the file. And even then, I would recommend against it.
- You read from the `<>` handle, which is standard input, or `ARGV`, depending on whether you give your program arguments or not. It is unclear if this is what you intended.
- When you check `index` of your sequence, you have not `chomp`ed your input, so it will unlikely match inside a string. (Unless there is no newline in your input file).
- You loop over the matches in your string, and check if the match is equal to some weird `$count` variable, which (actually) counts the matches, not the characters. Not sure what your intentions are there. Depending on whether the position of the match matches the count, you print it. And you print nothing else.

All in all, it is not surprising this does not work.

If all you want to do is replace your search string with dash and the rest with pipe, you can do something simple like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $sequence = <>); # assuming a one-line file
while (<>) {
    while (/(.)/g) {
        if ($1 eq $sequence) {
            print "-";
        } else {
            print "|";
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Usage:

```
perl program.pl input > output
```

If you only want to read the first line of a file, you can do as above, but note that if there are more lines in that file, they will be read by `<>`. To prevent that, you can explicitly `close ARGV` afterwards, which will make the progress skip ahead to the next file in `@ARGV`.

Comment: Thanks! What I was trying to do was to think of each letter as a numbered position instead. That way, I could print however many - until I get to the location where the sequence would match, then print a |, and then continue printing dashes until the next match is found, through the end of my file. Also, my input is not a blank file - I just did not include the directory. My output file is though. The $count variable is supposed to be the number of nucleotides in my file.